# How to run a global npm executable when the shell has a program with the same name

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, ubuntu, npm

I have installed `npm-check-updates` on my Ubuntu 18.04 system with `npm install -g npm-check-updates`. [This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) requires you to run it with `$ ncu` from the command line.

But when I try to run it using `ncu` the shell just executes a different weather update program that runs with the `ncu` command as well.

Is there a way to specify that you are trying to run the npm executable specifically? Thank you.

I want to run the **npm executable** and *not* the binary located at `/usr/local/bin/ncu`

Comment: Try “which ncu” and use absolute path to the executable you want

Comment: `which ncu` only shows the regular binary that the shell executes. I want to run the npm global package, not the binary that shows up with `which ncu`

Answer (score 0):

Run `whereis` to find where the binary images are.

```
⇒  whereis ncu
ncu: /usr/bin/ncu /usr/local/bin/ncu
```

For example, in my computer there is two `ncu`s located at `/usr/bin/ncu` and `/usr/local/bin/ncu`.

Then you could run it by its full path like:

```
⇒  /usr/bin/ncu      
No package.json
...
```

For more convenience you could define an alias for it in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` like:

```
alias ncu2="/usr/bin/ncu"
```

Comment: The `whereis` does not show the npm global executable, which is what I want to run. I do not want to run the binary at `/usr/bin/ncu`, and I would prefer not to have to change or remove this binary.

Comment: Actually the `/usr/bin/ncu` that I mentioned is the `ncu` that I installed with `npm install -g`. So, if you can't see it in `whereis` then the binary is not in your `$PATH` environment variable. I'm using fedora on my laptop since then I couldn't tell you exactly where the binary would be in ubuntu. Though, if you find it you can call it by its full path or aliasing it.

Comment: No, this is not the case. I have found the node executable in my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ncu` folder, but I'm not able to run it by it's full path. (`node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ncu/index.js` etc doesn't work)

Comment: Do you have `node` on your system? I realized that there is an another package called `node` on ubuntu. Try `nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules/npm-check-updates/bin/ncu` it should work if it is the case.